# What is a more professional term for the 'back-of-the-envelope' calculation?

Tags: phrases, idioms, synonyms, terminology, science

What is a more professional term for the phrase 'back-of-the-envelope' calculation, used by scientists and such as a word for a very basic, general first calculation?

Comment: Simple? Please include an example phrase where the term would be used. "Back-of-the-envelope" is a perfectly good expression. The reason I wouldn't use it in a peer-reviewed paper isn't because its register isn't "professional" enough but because such calculations have no business being reported in a journal.

Comment: I respectfully disagree - many peer-reviewed papers use these types of calculation as a basis for their studies, one example? Cao & Caldeira (2010) Atmospheric carbon dioxide removal: long-term consequences and commitment. _Environmental Rearch Letters_ ,5.

Comment: Similarly many numerical approaches need a set of initial values known as guesses. A robust technique *should* give answers independent of the guesses, but a good guess can make the model converge much more quickly. Testing a range of guesses can be important.

Comment: @AlexSpence but that's my point. If it is good enough to go in a journal, and you consider it a back of the envelope calculation, then call it a back of the envelope calculation. I assumed you meant a quick approximation, which is why I asked you for an example sentence in the first place. Otherwise, there's nothing wrong with the expression "back of the envelope" and indeed, [it appears quite often](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22back+of+the+envelope%22&btnG=) in published papers.

Comment: Preliminary model (one assumes the scientists can manage the maths involved, but are having difficulty formulating a definitive equation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Making a] [**Zeroth-order approximation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_approximation) [Wikipedia].

> In science, engineering, and other quantitative disciplines, orders of approximation refer to formal or informal terms for how precise an approximation is, and to indicate progressively more refined approximations: in increasing order of precision, a zeroth-order approximation, a first-order approximation, a second-order approximation, and so forth.

This not only has the advantage of sounding more formal, it implies a pathway toward more formal approximations.

Comment: 'First approximation' is probably the everyday equivalent of the technical 'zeroth approximation'. The Wikipedia article mentions this.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases *estimate* fits. I prefer *rough estimate* to reinforce the notion of arbitrary assumptions. With respect to your comment, *initial estimate* has a nice ring to it, and easily leads to *... based on* which is often appropriate.

*Back-of-the-envelope calculation* is more generally accepted than the (presumably only British) synonym *fag-packet calculation* (or *-- sketch* etc.) Another useful but fairly informal word is *guesstimate*, which you'll find in plenty of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

You can say preliminary or cursory calculations.

Comment: And how would the meaning of those phrases compare with "back-of-the-envelope calculation"? Is it really just a change of register, or does it change the meaning? We're generally looking for answers that give some detail, not just one-liners.