# A word for upper bounding a mathematical expression that turns out not to be tight enough to be of use

Tags: phrase-requests, translation

In my own native tongue (Hebrew) when I have some mathematical expression that is complicated and I try to upper bound it with a simpler expression but then I find out that the gap between the two is so big that it causes other problems I would say that my estimate of it was rough, coarse, crude or something like that (The exact words in Hebrew, if anyone wonders or cares would've been "גס מדי" pronounced "G-ass mee-dai", which, when translated literally would mean "Too rough", "Too rude" or "Too vulgar").

What would be a good word or expression to convey that miscalculation in English? The only things I came up with are "Too rough an estimate", "Too crude of an estimate" or "An unrefined estimate" and for the most part those would do just fine but I was wondering if there is anything else that would sound more natural in English (American or British) especially in an academic setting (I'm an electrical engineering grad student).

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean, that you used the wrong methodology to make the estimate, or didn't put enough time into the estimate, or made a mistake, or it was wrong for some other reason? ("Too crude", "too naive", or "too hasty" might be reasons.)

Comment: Do you mean specifically that the estimate was too *high,* or just that it was incorrect?

Comment: Or that your estimate was never intended to be very precise?

Comment: All your ideas work, even *overestimated* it. Too *gass* also means too gross, as in too bold and too big.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a more professional term for the 'back-of-the-envelope' calculation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/420865/what-is-a-more-professional-term-for-the-back-of-the-envelope-calculation) 'First approximation' / 'zeroth approximation' / 'rough estimate'. // The title question asks for a single word, while the tags ask for  a phrase. Please clarify.

Comment: @StuartF I mean as in made a mistake or chose something that made things easier but led to problems later on because it was too inaccurate - the gap between the thing being valued and my estimate for it was too big.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Not really, while it was something mathematical it was more of taking a simpler expression to upper bound a more complicated expression but then it turned out that the gap between the two was so big it led to issues so I had to go back and use the more complicated expression. Hope that clarifies. This should also answer the other comments here.

Comment: I've edited my question to reflect the difference between my question and other questions

Comment: Your original estimate *overshot* the mark (it went too far.)

Comment: @YosefBaskin That works, I think. Thanks.

Comment: *Rough estimate* or *crude estimate* may err both ways - I am not sure that this is the meaning that you want to convey. *(Significantly) overshoot/overestimate* is probably closer. Perhaps, you could provide a complete sentence (you could also try in the math or physics community, since it is a matter of terminology, rather than general English.)

Comment: The parameters were too broad or the parameters were set too broadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could say that your original bound was **too loose**.

When you get a bound that works, you can say that it is **tight enough**.

Comment: I'm still reluctant to use "loose" but I guess this is the best I have for now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may say that the amount was **overstated** (or exaggerated).

> Overstate : If you say that someone is overstating something, you mean
> they are describing it in a way that makes it seem more important or
> serious than it really is.
> [Source : Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/overstate)

Example: *In this report, import prices are overstated and overall inflation is understated*.

Answer (score 0):

You used the word "unrefined." Looking at the basis for the estimate, perhaps you could say that it was more a *guesstimate* than *estimate*.

**Guesstimate** (n.)

> An estimate usually made without adequate information [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/guesstimate)

> An estimate which is based on both guesswork and reasoning. [OED]

> An approximate calculation of the size or amount of something when you
> do not know all the facts [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/guesstimate)

Intuitively, I would say that a guesstimate is rougher than a very rough estimate. *Guesstimate* is sometimes labeled as *informal* and may not be suitable for all academic writing.

Comment: There wasn't much of a guess in it - it was mathematically sound but had no use because it wasn't tight enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could say your original method was was a

> **rule of thumb**
> A rough measure or method, without precise mathematical or scientific basis.

From [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/rule+of+thumb).

Comment: However, my upper bound had a mathematical basis and was correct. It was just too high to be of any use. Like saying that there are less than 1000 days  in a year - true but useless.

Comment: The extract says: without a *precise* mathematical basis.

Comment: The basis was precise, the bound wasn't tight so I don't think this really fits.